# Can you host Magento on Heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, heroku, amazon-rds

I know that you can run PHP on Heroku and use Amazon RDS for mySQL, but has anyone actually done it?

Comment: Well, I'm going to try it and I'll post my result if no one else has.

Comment: I'm sure you have more than enough google-fu, but in case you missed it, Ioannis Papadakis wrote a blog post on running Symfony2 on Heroku stating others should work to... http://blog.pajap.com/?p=102